# How to substract "Y:m:d H:i:s" from "Y:m:d H:i:s" and return result in "H:i"

Tags: php, mysql

I want to result of EndTime - StartTime to get Task Completed Time in This Format Like "02 Hours : 30 Mins". Both StartTime and EndTime is in this Format "Y:m:d H:i:s". I tried this but not giving correct output.

```
$starttime = $row['StartTime'];
$endtime = $row['EndTime'];

//method1
$starttime = date("H:i",$starttime);
$endtime = date("H:i",$endtime);
$start = strtotime($starttime);
$end = strtotime($endtime);
$achtime = $end-$start;
$achtime = date("H:i",$achtime);

//method2
$interval = date_diff($starttime,$endtime);
$achtime = date_format($interval,'H Hours : i Mins');
```

I tried both but not working.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DateTime Object.

```
$startDate = new DateTime("2018:08:18 00:00:00"); 
$endDate   = new DateTime("2018:08:18 02:10:00");
$interval  = $startDate->diff($endDate);

echo ($interval->days * 24) + $interval->h ." Hours : ". $interval->i ." Mins";
```

If you want to be very specific about the date being read, or the format you are being given isn't a supported format, then it is recommend to use DateTime object.

Answer (score 0):

$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

```
return $interval->format($differenceFormat);
```

Comment: OPs comment shows why answers need to be more than 2 lines of code which are not directly applicable to the question...